# No main activity when static analysis

Tags: android

Though `mainifest.xml`, I know main activity is: `com.trust.rookie.MainActivity`. But when I load the file in jadx, I can't see that class. Why? And how the program can run?

Comment: Make sure you have disabled the Jadx feature "Deobfuscation" to always see the original class names.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the sample is **packed**.
What you see in JADX is the packer's code. It unwraps/decrypts a payload DEX and then loads it (typically, look for `DexClassLoader`). This payload DEX has the main activity you are looking for.